# Determining limit using squeeze theorem.

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I apply the squeeze theorem for finding the limit of this problem? 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(|x|\cos^2\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$$

Comment: $0\leq|x|\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\leq|x|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
0 \le |x| \cos^2 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \le |x|
$$